# C - Creating a lookup table that returns data to a union: either a bitwise struct or a short

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to build a large static lookup table that has special cases. In general, it needs to return 3 states to a struct

```
typedef struct state{
  unsigned short speed : 3;
  unsigned short direction : 1;
  unsigned short size : 1;
}STATE;
```

but it has special cases which are simply stored in a short and the values are predefined. I wanted to use a union because it's a large table

```
typedef union instruction{
        STATE state;
        unsigned short rule;
}INSTRUCTION;
```

The table looks like:

```
static const INSTRUCTION table[2][2] = {
  {{STOP},{1,1,1}},
  {{4,0,0},{JUMP}}
};
```

The problem I am having is that the table only treats the first element in the union as the data type. I can't return STOP, because it puts the code for stop in speed. If I switch it around, the table ignores the additional values.

Any ideas how I can return data from the table without adding several additional flags in my struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a *designated initializer* to initialize the proper union member:

```
static const INSTRUCTION table[2][2] = {
  {{ .rule = STOP},    { .state = {1,1,1}}},
  {{ .state = {4,0,0}},{ .rule = JUMP}}
};
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thank you! It didn't work right away and i'm not sure what I changed, but it compiles and I tested it and it's perfect, but my IDE still highlights it as an error in my syntax.